# Styled-components: property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: typescript, styled-components

After I upgraded `@types/styled-components`  from `5.1.32`to `5.1.34` my compiler started do throw an error for styled components that has some custom props. Some example:

```
interface StyledContainerProps {
  disabled: boolean;
}

export const StyledContainer = styled.div<StyledContainerProps>`
  /* ... */
`;
```

And then in the component of the React app:

```
<StyledContainer disabled={isDisabled}>
 ...
</StyledContainer>
```

I'm getting an error:

> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { disabled: boolean; } & { theme?: any; } & { as?: string; forwardedAs?: string; }'.

The thing is that looking at `@types/styled-components` changelog nothing should be broken... Am I missing something? This has been the way to create a styled component in my app for a long time.

Answer (score 4):

In their latest release, @types/styled-components has replaced all instances of "JSX" with "React.JSX". However, the @types/react library still seems to be providing the JSX namespace as a global instead of being a part of the react module, which is causing any styled elements to not be able to inherit properties properly. The only solution I can think of right now is to downgrade @types/styled-components until @types/react makes the JSX namespace a part of the react module.

[Source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/ae87a41a1786c280b0c2a034b06a3457161fa6a8)

Comment: Thank you! But do you know which version of @types/styled-components I should downgrade to ?